# Is this sufficient to prevent header injection?

Tags: php, contact-form

In the code below that I had found on the internet and that i'm using for my contact form, the first part seems related to security:

```
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }
```

Is this code strong enough to prevent header injections / security issues? (I'm not familiar with PHP)

Thanks,

Full code:

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //send email
 mail( "dfdsfs@ddfdsfd.com", "From page: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message']."\nDepuis la page: ". str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) . "\n" . $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC: dfdsfds@dfdfds.com" );

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Injection usually occurs in databases, As far as code is concern , it is secure but more better way is to use htmlentities(), stripslashes() functions for this